# Selecting union of results of dataset-producing function when applied element-wise to an array

Tags: postgresql, optimization, psql, cte, many-to-many

This problem is somewhat an academic curiosity.  I'm attempting to implement a SQL (i.e. not plpgSQL) function which takes an array of input data, transforms each entry to a set of zero or more rows using some other black-box function, then returns the concatenation or the union of those resulting datasets.

I have a function which takes a value and returns zero or more records:

```
f: x -> y[]
```

I have another function which should take an array of `x` values as its input, and should apply `f` to each element, returning the union of all the returned record sets:

```
g: x[] -> y[], returning union or concatenation of { f(x) for each x in x[] }
```

Initially, I don't care whether the resulting set contains duplicates although it would be preferable if it did not.

I considered using a "recursive" CTE for this to iterate over the array.  Using the typical CTE example with tree structures:

```
create table node(id int primary key, parent_id int);

insert into node values                                                                                                                                                          
    (0, null),                                                                                                                                                                   
    (1, 0),                                                                                                                                                                      
    (2, 0),                                                                                                                                                                      
    (3, 2),                                                                                                                                                                      
    (4, 0),                                                                                                                                                                      
    (5, 1),                                                                                                                                                                      
    (6, 1),                                                                                                                                                                      
    (7, 1),                                                                                                                                                                      
    (8, 2),                                                                                                                                                                      
    (9, 3),                                                                                                                                                                      
    (10, 3);                                                                                                                                                                     

create function f(p_id int)                                                                                                                                                      
returns table (id int, parent_id int)                                                                                                                                            
as $$                                                                                                                                                                            
    select * from node where node.parent_id = p_id;                                                                                                                              
$$ language sql stable;                                                                                                                                                          

create function g(p_ids int[])                                                                                                                                                   
returns table (id int, parent_id int, x int)                                                                                                                                     
as $$                                                                                                                                                                            
    with recursive res(id, parent_id, i) as (                                                                                                                                    
        select null::int, null::int, array_lower(p_ids, 1)                                                                                                                       
        union all                                                                                                                                                                
        select tmp.id, tmp.parent_id, res.i + 1                                                                                                                                  
        from res, f(p_ids[res.i]) as tmp                                                                                                                                         
        where res.i <= array_upper(p_ids, 1)                                                                                                                                     
    ) select res.* from res where id is not null;                                                                                                                                
$$ language sql stable;                                                                                                                                                          

select * from f(2);                                                                                                                                                              

select * from g(ARRAY[2, 1]);
```

This works, and I can control whether or not I want duplicates via `union`/`union all`, but I'd assume that the explicit iteration would present an optimisation barrier, which could be quite bad if `data` was large, the array was long, and function `f(x)` was something stupidly simple such as:

```
select a, b, c from node where node.id = x
```

In which case the entire query could be optimised to be equivalent to a simple:

```
select a, b, c from node where node.id = any (xs)
```

But presumably couldn't be due to the planner being unable to realise that our iterative CTE part could be translated to a set operation.

--

I decided to not be lazy and to test this:

```
create function f2(p_ids int[])                                                                                                                                                  
returns table (id int, parent_id int)                                                                                                                                            
as $$                                                                                                                                                                            
    select * from node where node.parent_id = ANY ( p_ids );                                                                                                                     
$$ language sql stable;
```

Then with possibly my favourite feature of Postgres:

```
explain analyze select * from f(2);

 Seq Scan on node  (cost=0.00..38.25 rows=11 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=2 loops=1)
   Filter: (parent_id = 2)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 9
 Planning time: 0.051 ms
 Execution time: 0.012 ms
(5 rows)

explain analyze select * from f2(ARRAY[2, 1]);

 Seq Scan on node  (cost=0.00..38.25 rows=23 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=5 loops=1)
   Filter: (parent_id = ANY ('{2,1}'::integer[]))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 6
 Planning time: 0.055 ms
 Execution time: 0.013 ms
(5 rows)

explain analyze select * from g(ARRAY[2, 1]);

 CTE Scan on res  (cost=424.46..431.28 rows=339 width=12) (actual time=0.026..0.046 rows=8 loops=1)
   Filter: (id IS NOT NULL)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1
   CTE res
     ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..424.46 rows=341 width=12) (actual time=0.002..0.042 rows=9 loops=1)
           ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=1)
           ->  Hash Join  (cost=0.26..41.76 rows=34 width=12) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=3 loops=3)
                 Hash Cond: (node.parent_id = ('{2,1}'::integer[])[res_1.i])
                 ->  Seq Scan on node  (cost=0.00..32.60 rows=2260 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=11 loops=2)
                 ->  Hash  (cost=0.22..0.22 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=3)
                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
                       ->  WorkTable Scan on res res_1  (cost=0.00..0.22 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=3)
                             Filter: (i <= 2)
                             Rows Removed by Filter: 2
 Planning time: 0.255 ms
 Execution time: 0.083 ms
(16 rows)
```

Is there a better way to implement this `select-many`, ideally a purely set-based method which would not present optimisation barriers?

I'm aware that an index on `parent_id` would help if the table were much larger however I'm more interested in how the iterative query could be expressed differently to improve performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved via `unnest` or by modifying the original array-returning function to return a `table`/`setof` instead.

The function application can then be done within a `join`.